# Auto adjust size of QLabel according to text it contains

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlabel

I have a QLabel and I would like to adjust the size of it, according to the text it contains (plus some margin on the sides)., I've tried this:

```
self.WarnLab = QtGui.QLabel(self.HeaderRight)
font = QtGui.QFont()
font.setFamily(_fromUtf8("Avenir"))
font.setPointSize(18)
font.setBold(True)
font.setItalic(False)
font.setWeight(75)
self.WarnLab.setFont(font)
self.WarnLab.setObjectName("WarnLab")
r = self.WarnLab.fontMetrics().boundingRect(_translate("MainWindow","This is some, \nlonger multi-line text blahblahblah!",None))
self.WarnLab.fixedWidth(r.width())
self.WarnLab.fixedHeight(r.height())
self.WarnLab.setStyleSheet(_fromUtf8("QLabel { background-color : orange; color : white;}"))
self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.WarnLab, 0,0,0,0)
```

but `QLabel` doesn't have a property `fixedWidth()`, i.e. this won't work. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to set fixed dimensions in the widgets then you must use the [`setFixedWidth()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedWidth), [`setFixedHeight()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedHeight) and/or [`setFixedSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#setFixedSize):

```
self.WarnLab.setFixedSize(r.size())
```

or

```
self.WarnLab.setFixedWidth(r.width())
self.WarnLab.setFixedHeight(r.height())
```

---

<sub>If you want to know all the methods of QLabel or any other widget you should check the docs of Qt, for example [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlabel.html) is the docs of QLabel, and if you want all the methods you must click on the section ["List of all members, including inherited members"](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlabel-members.html) .</sub>